# parsing FireFox bookmarks using regular expression

Tags: json, firefox, grep, bookmarks

I tried to parse firefox bookmark(JSON exported version), using this efforts:

```
cat boo.json | grep '\"uri\"\:\"^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\"'
cat boo.json | grep '"uri"\:"^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}'
cat boo.json | grep '"uri"\:"^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}"'
```

And few others but all fails, json bookmarked file will look like this:

```
.........."uri":"http://www.google.com/?"......"uri":"http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

So, the output should be like this:

```
"uri":"http://www.google.com/?"
"uri":"http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

What is the missing part on my regular expression?

**UPDATE:**

Url's on bookmark file ending with one of this  special character:

`/`, **ex:** `"uri":"http://stackoverflow.com/"`

`"`, **ex:** `"uri":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148794/parsing-firefox-bookmarks-using-regular-expression"`

`}`, **ex:** `"uri":"https://fr.add-ons.mozilla.com/fr/firefox/bookmarks/"}`

With this modified regular expression:

```
$ egrep -o "(http|https)://([^ ]*).(*\/)"  boo.json
```

Result:

```
http://fr.fxfeeds.mozilla.com/fr/firefox/headlines.xml"},{"name":"livemark/siteURI","flags":0,"expires":4,"mimeType":null,"type":3,"value":"http://www.lemonde.fr/"}],"type":"text/x-moz-place-container","children":[]}]},{"index":2,"title":"Tags","id":4,"parent":1,"dateAdded":1344432674984000,"lastModified":1344432674984000,"type":"text/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148794/parsing-firefox-bookmarks-using-regular-expression","charset":"UTF-8"},{"index":29,"title":"adrusi/
http://stackoverflow.com/
...
```

But with this still doesn't get me only url's.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with JSON format but from the very small snippet you posted it LOOKS like it'd be a very brief, simple awk script to pull out the URLs. If you posted a bit more sample input (say a 10-line file) and expected output, I'd take a look.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mr Jeff Atwood had posted an article [the problem with urls](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html), With his proposed Regular Expression, I managed to extract all the url's from FireFox bookmark:

```
egrep -o "\(?\bhttp://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]"  my-bookmark.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JSON.sh? Its works great!

https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh

Comment: What do you mean it doenst work? Did you use it that way that the README says to? It'll still need some parsing, but this will get you a standard output for any JSON from which to extract values

Answer (score 0):

I use this regex to extract urls , it's works great

`cat *.html | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" | sort | uniq`